Angular Direct Routing Not Working When Copying and Pasting URL
I'm facing an issue with routing in my Angular application. When I directly copy and paste a URL into the browser (e.g., https://myapp.dev/material-details/bd3d31dd-945a-4faf-a888-be43204d6a85/attributes), it sometimes redirects to the root of the application (https://myapp.dev) instead of navigating to the intended route ( material-details).
This works properly via routeLink _router.navigate
Here’s an example of my route configuration and ngModule of app.module:
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'material-details/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./material-details/material-details.module').then(m => m.MaterialDetailsModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ReserveMaterialComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DashboardModule,
    BlockUIModule.forRoot({
      delayStart: 300,
      delayStop: 0
    }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 10000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
      closeButton: true,
      enableHtml: true
    }),
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [PageService, GroupService, SortService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

the custom module :
imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '', component: MaterialDetailsComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: 'attributes', component: DynamicTabComponent },
                    // { path: 'documents', component: DynamicTabComponent },
                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'attributes', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'attributes', pathMatch: 'full' }
                ]
            }
        ]),
        SharedModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],

What I've Tried:

Verified that RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true }) is
properly configured.
Tried using both useHash: true and useHash:
false with no success.
Checked for any canActivate guards that might
be interfering.
Compared with another project where direct URL
navigation works fine, but couldn't identify significant
differences.

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that the correct component loads when a user navigates directly to a URL?

why are you using useHash option ?

put { path: '', redirectTo: 'attributes', pathMatch: 'full' }, before                     { path: 'attributes', component: DynamicTabComponent },

the URL you show in your question does not include the hash, so something's wrong there. the URL should show like: ...index.html#/material-details/...   Include code that generates the link you copied.
